# How do I add a rubber band for mouse dragging in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I made the second code separate from the first and I wanted to implement the same functionality as the second which is to draw a line with the mouse I made the second code separate from the first and I wanted to implement the same functionality of the second which is to draw a line with the mouse

```py
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 750
background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\honeycomb.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(BACKGROUND, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

img1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\As.png")
img2 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsXOR.png")
img3 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsNOT.png")
img4 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsAND.png")
images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]
current_image = -1
img_rects = [images[i].get_rect(topleft=(20 + 40 * i, 20)) for i in range(len(images))]
img_angles = [0 for _ in range(len(images))]

LeftButton = 0
while 1:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(e.pos, (1, 1))
            current_image = mouse_rect.collidelist(img_rects)

        if e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                rel = e.rel
                if 0 <= current_image < len(images):
                    img_rects[current_image].x += rel[0]
                    img_rects[current_image].y += rel[1]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        img_angles[current_image] -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        img_angles[current_image] += 1

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    for i in range(len(images)):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(images[i], img_angles[i])
        rotated_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=img_rects[i].center)
        screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

how i can add a line like in the code below in this code ?

```py
def main()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Mouse Draw")
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    rect = surface.get_rect()
    fps = 60

    line_surface = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    line_surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))

    mouse_position = None
    display_line = None
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if mouse_position:
                    display_line = mouse_position, event.pos
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if mouse_position:
                        pygame.draw.line(line_surface, pygame.Color("red"), mouse_position, event.pos)
                        mouse_position = None
                        display_line = None
                    else:
                        mouse_position = event.pos

        surface.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
        surface.blit(line_surface, (0, 0))

        if display_line:
            pygame.draw.line(surface, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), *display_line)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
main ()
```

I would like to put the def main in the first code but I don’t always see a black screen or it gives an error and I would be very grateful if someone could help me.
in fact i would like to join the two codes, but i don't know how to adapt the to fit the first

Comment: You haven't specified where or when you want a line drawn. It's unclear what you're asking - are you asking how the `*display_line` argument unpacking works in order to use `mouse_position, event.pos` as the line's starting and ending points?

Comment: yess this is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to draw lines with a click and click, you have to save the starting position with the first click and end the line with the second click. The lines have to be stored to a list. Add a list of liens and a variable `line_start` and initialize it by `None`:

```py
lines = []
line_start = None
```

Set the start with the first click and end the line with the second click (`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`). Add the finished line to the list of lines:

```py
if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        # [...]

        if line_start:
            lines.append((line_start, e.pos))
            line_start = None
        else:
            line_start = e.pos
```

Draw the lines in a loop. If a line is started bunt not finished draw a line form the start position to the current mouse position:

```py
for line in lines:
    pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), *line)
if line_start:
    pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), line_start, pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\honeycomb.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(BACKGROUND, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

img1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\As.png")
img2 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsXOR.png")
img3 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsNOT.png")
img4 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsAND.png")

images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]

current_image = -1
img_rects = [images[i].get_rect(topleft=(20 + 80 * i, 20)) for i in range(len(images))]
img_angles = [0 for _ in range(len(images))]

lines = []
line_start = None

LeftButton = 0
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(e.pos, (1, 1))
            current_image = mouse_rect.collidelist(img_rects)
            if line_start:
                lines.append((line_start, e.pos))
                line_start = None
            else:
                line_start = e.pos

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                rel = e.rel
                if 0 <= current_image < len(images):
                    img_rects[current_image].x += rel[0]
                    img_rects[current_image].y += rel[1]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if 0 <= current_image < len(img_angles):
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            img_angles[current_image] -= 1
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            img_angles[current_image] += 1

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    for line in lines:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), *line)
    if line_start:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), line_start, pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    for i in range(len(images)):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(images[i], img_angles[i])
        rotated_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = img_rects[i].center)
        screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

---

If you want to draw a rubber line while dragging an icon, you must save the start of the line. Add a variable `line_start` and initialize it by `None:

```py
line_start = None
```

Set the start position when the mouse is pressed (`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`):

```py
if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(e.pos, (1, 1))
    current_image = mouse_rect.collidelist(img_rects)
    line_start = e.pos
```

Set the `line_start = None` when the mouse is released (`MOUSEBUTTONUP`):

```py
if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    line_start = None
```

If `line_start` is set, draw a line from the start position ot the current mouse position:

```py
if line_start:
    pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), line_start, pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\honeycomb.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(BACKGROUND, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

img1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\As.png")
img2 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsXOR.png")
img3 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsNOT.png")
img4 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsAND.png")

images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]

current_image = -1
img_rects = [images[i].get_rect(topleft=(20 + 80 * i, 20)) for i in range(len(images))]
img_angles = [0 for _ in range(len(images))]

line_start = None

LeftButton = 0
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(e.pos, (1, 1))
            current_image = mouse_rect.collidelist(img_rects)
            line_start = e.pos

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            line_start = None

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                rel = e.rel
                if 0 <= current_image < len(images):
                    img_rects[current_image].x += rel[0]
                    img_rects[current_image].y += rel[1]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if 0 <= current_image < len(img_angles):
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            img_angles[current_image] -= 1
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            img_angles[current_image] += 1

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    if line_start:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), line_start, pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    for i in range(len(images)):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(images[i], img_angles[i])
        rotated_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = img_rects[i].center)
        screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

---

If you want to draw lines along the way the icons are dragged, you need a list of lines. Each line is a list of points:

```py
lines = []
```

Start a new list when the mouse is pressed (`MOUSEMOTION`):

```py
if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(e.pos, (1, 1))
    current_image = mouse_rect.collidelist(img_rects)
    lines.append([e.pos])                                 # <---
```

Add a point to the last line in the list of lines when the mouse is moved (`MOUSEMOTION`):

```py
if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
    if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
        rel = e.rel
        if 0 <= current_image < len(images):
            img_rects[current_image].x += rel[0]
            img_rects[current_image].y += rel[1]
            lines[-1].append(e.pos)                      # <---
```

Draw the lines in a loop, unsing [`pygame.draw.lines`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines):

```py
for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 1:
        pygame.draw.lines(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), False, line)
```

[image]

If you want straight lines, you have to replace the 2nd point of the line with the new mouse position when you move the mouse:

```py
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                rel = e.rel
                if 0 <= current_image < len(images):
                    img_rects[current_image].x += rel[0]
                    img_rects[current_image].y += rel[1]
                    
                    # lines[-1].append(e.pos)
                    if len(lines[-1]) < 2:
                        lines[-1].append(e.pos)
                    else:
                        lines[-1][1] = e.pos
```

[image]

---

Minimal example:

You can switch between the two implementations by changing the value of `straight_lines`.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\honeycomb.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(BACKGROUND, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

img1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\As.png")
img2 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsXOR.png")
img3 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsNOT.png")
img4 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ga-sa\Downloads\AssetsAND.png")

images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]

current_image = -1
img_rects = [images[i].get_rect(topleft=(20 + 80 * i, 20)) for i in range(len(images))]
img_angles = [0 for _ in range(len(images))]

lines = []

# straight_lines = False 
straight_lines = True

LeftButton = 0
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_rect = pygame.Rect(e.pos, (1, 1))
            current_image = mouse_rect.collidelist(img_rects)
            lines.append([e.pos])

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                rel = e.rel
                if 0 <= current_image < len(images):
                    img_rects[current_image].x += rel[0]
                    img_rects[current_image].y += rel[1]
                    
                    if len(lines[-1]) < 2 or not straight_lines:
                        lines[-1].append(e.pos)
                    else:
                        lines[-1][1] = e.pos

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if 0 <= current_image < len(img_angles):
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            img_angles[current_image] -= 1
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            img_angles[current_image] += 1

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            pygame.draw.lines(screen, pygame.Color('lawngreen'), False, line)
    
    for i in range(len(images)):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(images[i], img_angles[i])
        rotated_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = img_rects[i].center)
        screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```